# file association locked

Tags: perl, cgi, aptana

I am doing perl cgi programming, and have Aptana installed.

Aptana "locks" *.cgi to ruby, which means that I get ruby errors reported on what is actually a perl script.

Is there a known workaround, I'm currently editing as a .pl file & then copying to cgi for testing .. but this is not optimal as the errors are misleading

Comment: Can you right click on the .cgi file and open it in a different editor (whatever you are using for .pl files)? Once you have chosen an alternate editor for a given file it will default there. Unfortunately you have to do this for each file.

Comment: I am having this same issue and have tried what you suggest, but I still get Ruby errors. I have even installed EPIC and set the file association for .cgi to perl, but continue to get these errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the error markers by right-clicking on them in the Problems window. This worked for me, at least for now.